# Controlling a mapbox map from an outside form

Tags: javascript, forms, autocomplete, mapbox

I have a mapbox map and an independent, visually separated form with input fields for country,city,street.
All examples I've found to position a location in a mapbox map use an input field with autocomplete.

This is not what I want.
The auto-positioning of the map should only start after I press a button with onclick=... associated with this form reading the form's data.
Is there a complete(!) example for that?

The relevant HTML:

```
<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ...';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map', 
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
center: [8.54, 47.37],
zoom: 9 
</script>
<form id='mapform' >
<input id='country' value='ES'/>
<input id='city' value='Barcelona'/>
<input id=street' value='Carrer de Balmes'/>
</form>
<div class='button' onclick='locate();'>Locate</div>
```

and the JS script fragment to be completed (jQuery is implemented):

```
function locate() {
  // you may suggest jQuery here:
  var wCountry = $("#mapform input[id=country]").val();
  var wCity = $("#mapform input[id=city]").val();
  var wStreet = $("#mapform input[id=street]").val();
  map.?????  
};
```

Comment: Your `new mapboxgl.Map` has no closing brackets.

Comment: In your `locate()` function, you have to somehow translate the form input (address) to coordinates (latitude and longitude). You might use [geocoding API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#geocoding).